# Symfony on Apache rewrites /login path to /web/login

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to set up a Symfony 3.4 project on an Apache (2.4.25) server. However, I'm facing issues with the rooting.

The application works smoothly with the built-in server (all routes). However, on Apache server, I'm unable to access the login page. The `/login` path is automatically change to `web/login` and result in:

> No route found for "GET /web/login/"

Since the application (and the routing) is working with the built-in server, I suspect an issue in the apache configuration. In the built-in server, the `/login` isn't rewrite.

**Note**:

- All the others routes reachable without being logged in are working.
- Symfony 3.4
- Apache 2.4.25

---

Here the **Apache files**:

`.htaccess` in the `web` folder:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# startpage (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewritting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the startpage because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # cache-bust assets url rewrite
    # Example format: /cpv-10/js/test123.js -> /js/test123.js
    # This allows us to change the asset version and "bust" intermediate caches (like varnish)
    # See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ref-framework-assets-version
    # See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-version-format
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^cpv-\d+\/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

    # The following rewrites all other queries to the front controller. The
    # condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual
    # hosting, the base path will be prepended to allow proper resolution of the
    # app.php file; it will work in non-aliased environments as well, providing
    # a safe, one-size fits all solution.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the startpage to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

`site.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.fr

    DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony/web

    <Directory /var/www/symfony/web>
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         Allow from All

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.fr
        ServerAlias www.domain.fr

        DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal-site
        <Directory /var/www/drupal-site>
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Symfony files:**

`app/config/routing.yml`

```
carte:
    resource: "@CarteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

reservation:
    # loads routes from the PHP annotations of the controllers
    resource: '@ReservationBundle/Controller/'
    type:     annotation

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

user_bundle:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin


homepage:
    path:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }

# Lexik Paybox Bundle
lexik_paybox:
    resource: '@LexikPayboxBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'


lexik_paybox_sample_return:
    path:     /payment/return/{status}
    defaults: { _controller: LexikPayboxBundle:Sample:return, status: error }
    requirements:
        status: success|canceled|denied
```

`src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`:

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

sonata_admin_dashboard:
    path:  /admin/dashboard
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Admin:index" }

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml
```

`app/config/security.yml`

```
security:

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_CLIENT]
        ROLE_CONTROLEUR:  [ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_CONTROLEUR]
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_CONTROLEUR, ROLE_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_CONTROLEUR, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: fos_userbundle
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.security.login_form_authenticator

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
        api_password_reset:
            pattern: ^/password/reset
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/reservation/+\d, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/reservation/edition/+\d, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/reservation/from_code, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/reservation/creation, role: ROLE_CLIENT }
        - { path: ^/pecheur, role: ROLE_CLIENT }
        - { path: ^/controleur, role: ROLE_CONTROLEUR }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

Output from `php bin/console debug:router fos_user_security_login`:

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                     |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | fos_user_security_login                                   |
| Path         | /login                                                    |
| Path Regex   | #^/login$#s                                               |
| Host         | ANY                                                       |
| Host Regex   |                                                           |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                       |
| Method       | GET|POST                                                  |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                 |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                           |
| Defaults     | _controller: fos_user.security.controller:loginAction     |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler   |
| Callable     | FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Stack Traces

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
No route found for "GET /web/login/"

  at vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:128
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
  at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
  at call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:139)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:127)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:169)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (web/app.php:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that might help other people one day. 
I solved it after trying to debug with a test function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 * @return Response
 */
public function testAction(){
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
}
```

Then I went on "/test" page from the web browser and the `login` appears !

I suspect this was a problem of cache or something like this...